# Facebook: auth flow is not allowed

Tags: javascript, facebook

I followed Facebook online dev. docs, but web API responds with:

> "Platform auth flow is not allowed: The application has disabled this authentication flow."

What should I turn on or off in order to make valid API calls?

Comment: What auth flows have you enabled in the app's security settings? what auth flow are you trying to use in your code?

Comment: I see there 4 switches there, all of them are turned on

Comment: This is what I use: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login, meens OAuth

Comment: That's the client side flow referred to in the error message; if your app settings definitely allow this flow and it's still not working, you should file a bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Answer (score 13):

If you get the *"Platform auth flow is not allowed: The application has disabled this authentication flow."* error, then you have probably not enabled the OAuth client login flow for your app. To enable this, visit your app's settings page, click on Advanced, scroll down to the Client OAuth login box and make sure that it is ON. Then scroll to the bottom of the page and save the changes.

If this did not work, double-check whether you've inserted the correct App ID in your app.

[image: Facebook: App Settings -> Advanced]

[image: Facebook: Settings -> Security -> Client OAuth Login]

[image: Facebook: App settings -> Save]

Comment: u could check the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39265251/1214383 for the current facebook setting UI.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You need to enable Client OAuth Login in your Facebook App Settings.
It comes under the product Section. If there is no product. First you have to add the product Facebook Login and then you can enable the login..

Comment: yes, this is the right place. it costs me 3 hours until I found the reason for the error.