# Friendsmash facebook tutorial

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

Hi I hope some one can help.  I've been following the Friendsmash tutorial to learn how to write facebook apps.  I am very new to programming and have come stuck.  I can't seem to get the log in to appear for first users of the app.

My core.js file looks like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

showHome();

```
 $( document ).on( 'click', 'button.play', function() {
    onPlay();
  });

  $( document ).on( 'click', '#gameover button.close', onGameOverClose );

  $( document ).on( 'mousedown', '#canvas', onGameCanvasMousedown );

  FB.init({
  appId: '452032718270713',
  frictionlessRequests: true,
  status: true,
  version: 'v2.3'
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', onAuthResponseChange);
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', onStatusChange);
});
```

and the social.js file looks like

```
function login(callback) {
  FB.login(callback);
}
function loginCallback(response) {
  console.log('loginCallback',response);
  if(response.status != 'connected') {
    top.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/pdhwebdevelopment';
  }
}
function onStatusChange(response) {
  if( response.status != 'connected' ) {
    login(loginCallback);
  } else {
    showHome();
  }
}
function onAuthResponseChange(response) {
  console.log('onAuthResponseChange', response);
}
```

I have also included the sdk in the head of index.php

Thanks for any help

Comment: As you can tell I didn't get far in the tutorial and seems a shame to give up but I have a lot to learn.

Comment: I'm getting this error in the console " Platform auth flow is not allowed: The application has disabled this authentication flow. "

Comment: If I create a test app it works?

Comment: The message you’re getting in console means your FB app is configured wrong. Go to your app dashboard, and check the settings.

Comment: @PaulHaskett, you should be able to find the steps to get past this error message [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393172/facebook-auth-flow-is-not-allowed)

Comment: Thanks I have given up with this I followed those steps and still didn't work so I think it may a facebook problem?